# Help understanding proof of connection between conditional expectation and PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

This is a TeX'd repost of [Connection of expectation and PDE; help understanding step in proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606116/connection-of-expectation-and-pde-help-understanding-step-in-proof), which did not get much attention.

> **Some preliminaries**: $\mathcal{A}$ is the generator of an Ito process $X_s^{t,x}$. The superscript on $X$ denotes that it starts at
>   time $t$ with a value of $x$.

I am having trouble understanding a particular step in the proof of the following theorem (displayed in ***bold italics*** at the end of the proof).

### Theorem

Suppose $v(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[g(X_{T}^{t,x})]\in
C^{1,2}([0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then, \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\mathcal{A}v & =0 & \text{on
}[0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^{n};\\ v & =g & \text{on
}\{T\}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}. \end{align*}

### Proof

Given $(t,x)$, let $\tau= T\wedge\inf\{s>t\colon|X_{s}^{t,x}-x|\geq1\}$.

Letting $s>t$, the Markov property of ensures
$$
v(t,x)=\mathbb{E}\left[v(\left(s\right)\wedge\tau,X_{\left(s\right)\wedge\tau}^{t,x})\right].
$$
Since $v$ is smooth enough, we can apply Itô's formula to expand
the integrand in the expectation:
\begin{align*}
0&=\mathbb{E}\left[v(\left(s\right)\wedge\tau,X_{\left(s\right)\wedge\tau}^{t,x})-v(t,x)\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{s\wedge\tau}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\mathcal{A}v\right)(u,X_{u}^{t,x})du\right]
+\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{s\wedge\tau}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(u,X_{u}^{t,x})\sigma(u,X_{u}^{t,x})dW_{u}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{s\wedge\tau}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\mathcal{A}v\right)(u,X_{u}^{t,x})du\right].
\end{align*}
The vanishing Itô integral term was guaranteed by the choice of $\tau$
so that $X_{u}^{t,x}$ is bounded on $[t,s\wedge \tau]$. We send $s\downarrow t$, and ***the
required result follows from the dominated convergence theorem***.